# Ruby: How does method chaining with block iterators work?

Tags: ruby

The below code seems to work. I'm not sure why though... as far as I know the `.each_char` takes a code block as does the `select` method. So I'm new at all Ruby and apologize if this question has been asked before.

**Here is the code:**

```
def word_test(word)
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    word_vowels = Hash.new()

    word_vowels = word.to_s.each_char.select {|char| vowels.include?(char)}
    if word_vowels == word_vowels.sort
        return true
    end
end

word_test("hello")
```

*How is it possible to append methods that require code blocks onto methods?*

Comment: By reading the fine manual: ["Passes each character in *str* to the given block, or returns an enumerator if no block is given."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_char).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_char). "Passes each character in str to the given block, or returns an enumerator if no block is given." This frase "or returns an enumerator if no block is given" appears frequently in Ruby doc's - it's what makes this "stacking methods on top of each other" useful. Actually it's called "method chaining".

Sidenote:

```
if word_vowels == word_vowels.sort
    return true
end

#better:

word_vowels == word_vowels.sort
```

Comment: thank you. so in the case that i mentioned, the .each method passes on an enumerator to .select, which provides an argument to the enumerator, which is effectively an argument for the .each method?

Comment: @ZachSmith The `each_char` transforms the string into a "virtual array" of chars. That is: it's not an array but it behaves like one -you can iterate over it. Better still, because enumerators are enumerable (literally they include the enumerable module), they have [a lot of powerful methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html), `select` being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`each_char` either takes a block which will be called for each character in the string, or it will return an Enumerator object which can be used for other purposes. In this case it looks like this is a round-about way to select all vowels from a string.

A much more efficient method is:

```
def test_word(word)
  word.match(/[aeiou]/i)
end
```

That basically does it in one shot. Regular expressions are very powerful if used correctly.

Comment: That's not what it's doing. It's checking if vowels appear in alphabetical order in the given word.

Comment: The original method is also case sensitive, although that's maybe not intended. `s = word.scan(/[aeiou]/); s == s.sort` should yield the equivalent result

Comment: @p11y Ah, good catch. The original method is muddled enough that wasn't clear.